# Spans of Normal-Width Spaces Within a Justified Text

Tags: html, css, spacing, text-alignment, justify

Here is my situation: I have a container element where all text inside must be justified. However, some inline elements within the container —certain important phrases in the text— must have regular-sized, non-justified spaces.
Here is an example:

```
<div style="text-align: justified;" >
<!-- A list of tags, let's say -->
sauna farming apples towels car(non-justified space)lifting
carpet(non-justified space)stealing football owls
</div>
```

```html
<div style="text-align: justified;">
  sauna farming apples towels car lifting carpet stealing football owls
</div>
```

What is the most efficient solution? My first attempt was to use a &nbsp; entity, without realizing that they followed the same justification rules. As far as I am aware, there isn't a unicode character or HTML entity with the exact size of a regular space meant to be used as a space character, for this situation. Would it be best practice to wrap them in a span tag, with some CSS styling? And if so, what style would prevent the justification? Should I follow a different method of organizing the text entirely, to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Please create a snippet for clarification.

Comment: @AmanSharma I have edited the question to provide an example

Comment: Just `display:inline-block` appears to work just fine; although then you'd have to live with that those elements won't break from one line to the next any more. But it looks like you want this for word combinations that belong together to begin with, so that might be fine.

Answer (score 0):

After testing out the solution provided by @cbroe, I have decided that it works for my needs. To clarify: wrapping the phrases in a span tag with `display: inline-block;` prevents the spaces within the spans from growing. This also prevents the phrases from breaking, however, this was something desirable, so I made no effort to change this behavior.
An example:

```
<style>
div{
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: right; /* not part of the solution, just aesthetic */
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<div><!-- A list of tags -->
bees quaternion consternation wimbeldon belladonna <span>salted caramel</span> nice
<span>waste management</span> <span>carpet deodorizer</span> telephony artifact equation
<span>rose garden</span>
</div>
```